# get error: Segmentation fault(core dumped) when run docker-machine

Tags: docker-machine

I download the latest build of docker-machine from github to /usr/local/bin/docker-machine on my Centos 7, and chmod x for it.

When I run it as `docker-machine -v`, the error as below:

> Segmentation fault(core dumped).

I run strace docker-machine:

```
execve("docker-machine", ["docker-machine"], [/* 35 vars */]) = 0
 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x2690388)      = 0
 --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x7ffba5531788} ---
 +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
```

who can help me for the error?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention which docker-machine version you are trying to install. However if you want to install docker-machine V0.8.0 try the following-

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.8.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine && \

chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

It solved my "segmentation fault" problem. Hope it will work you